# How does Meepo share experience?

Tags: dota-2

How does Meepo share experience?
I am especially interested in teem fights. Let's say 2 Meepos with 2 allies killed a hero, will Meepo get 1 share out of 3 or 2 out of 4?
Does Meepo's share depends on how many meepos are out of the fight area?  Will Meepo share exp if 1 Meepo assisted (but didn't lasthit), but it wasn't the main Meepo (the main Meepo was at home during the fight)?

Answer (score 4):

Each Meepo account for 1 hero which means if a kill happens and there are 2 Meepos and 2 allied heroes, Meepo will get half the experience. Same goes with lane creeps so when playing meepo you have to be very careful about not taking all the experience on the map. That's why most Meepo players stack neutrals, farm them and simultaneously farm one lane of creeps.

Each Meepo account for 1 hero in the XP distribution but 1/2/3/4/5 Meepos count as one hero when it comes to pick the formula that calculate the amount of experience gained from a kill (X Meepos + Y allied = 1 + Y Heroes : *The number of meepo doesnt matter*). Let's take a quick example : You have 4 allied Heroes and your 5 Meepos that just killed an enemy hero (above level 5) which mean you use the forumula for 4 allied + 1 (X Meepo) = 5 Heroes :

- The amount of XP (called A) given to your team is calculated as follow : `A = 5 x VictimLevel + XPFactor x 0.12`, which is the formula for 5 Heroes
- This amount of XP A is then shared between all Hero (and here Each Meepo account for 1). That means Meepo will get 5/9 of A while every other Hero will recieve 1/9 of A.

Comment: Thanks. Then there can be 9 "heroes" in a teem. What is the formula for sharing exp in this case? at gamepedia there is only 5-or-less-heros formula: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Experience .

Comment: @klm123 that is actually an excellent question and I will have to check that. You actuallly make me doubt my answer is correct, I'll be back to you as soon as I get the answer and I'll edit it if necessary.

Comment: @klm123 edited my answer, hope you understand, if no don't hesitate to ask for clarification :)

Comment: I understand what you mean (it must be All Meepos instead of 3 Meepos, right?) But this seems to not agree with gamepedia and common sense. 5 x VictimLevel + XPFactor x 0.12 should be xp given to one hero, not whole teem, shouldn't it? Otherewise dependence on n participants is quadratical and amount of xp in team fights is negligible with comparison with 1vs1 fight. How did you get this statements of yours?

Comment: Ive always thought that each group of Meepo within a same xp range would account for one hero. So if you habe 3 meepo and one hero, it´s half each. But meepo has the advantage on covering more ground and therefore being present in a bigger xp range. Are you 100% sure that with 5 meepos he would get 5/9 in the xp? (Considerinr your exact example ofc)

Comment: @Zil yes I'm sure. Wha't I'm still not sure of and tried to understand is which formula is used when a kill ocur with 4 allied and X number of Meepos arround.